# Reset object values after cancel form

Tags: vue.js

I have object like this:

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Checklist",
        "detail": [
            {
                "label": "Filter OK?",
                "type": "text"
            },
            {
                "label": "Package OK?",
                "type": "boolean"
            }
        ],
        "created_at": "2021-04-15T20:31:04.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-04-16T13:44:36.000000Z"
    },..]
```

table with listed objects -> **this.list = dataList.data;**

```
<el-table v-loading="listLoading" :data="list" size="mini" stripe fit highlight-current-row style="width: 100%">
  <el-table-column align="left" label="" width="150">
    <template slot-scope="{row}">
      <el-button-group>
        <el-button type="primary" size="mini" icon="el-icon-folder-opened" @click="handleUpdate(row)" />
        <el-button type="danger" size="mini" icon="el-icon-delete" @click="deleteData(row)" />
      </el-button-group>
    </template>
  </el-table-column>
<el-table-column min-width="200px" align="left" :label="$t('position.name')">
    <template slot-scope="scope">
      <span>{{ scope.row.name }}</span>
    </template>
  </el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

then I just click for open one row - handleUpdate(row)

```
handleUpdate(row) {
  this.temp = Object.assign({}, row);
  this.dialogFormVisible = true;
  this.dialogStatus = 'update';
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.$refs['dataForm'].clearValidate();
  });
},
```

then a dialog appears

```
<el-dialog :title="textMap[dialogStatus]" :visible.sync="dialogFormVisible">
  <el-form ref="dataForm" :rules="rules" :model="temp" label-position="right" label-width="90px" style="width: 400px; margin-left:50px;">
    <el-form-item :label="$t('position.name')" prop="name">
      <el-input v-model="temp.name" />
    </el-form-item>
    <el-divider />
    <el-form-item v-for="(item, index) in temp.detail" :key="index" prop="detail">
      <el-input v-model="item.name" />
    </el-form-item>
    <el-divider />
    <el-input v-model="checklistItem" placeholder="Nová položka" class="input-with-select">
      <el-button slot="append" icon="el-icon-plus" @click="addChecklistItem()" />
    </el-input>
  </el-form>
  <div slot="footer" class="dialog-footer">
    <el-button @click="dialogFormVisible = false">
      {{ $t('table.cancel') }}
    </el-button>
    <el-button type="primary" @click="dialogStatus==='create'?createData():updateData()">
      {{ $t('table.save') }}
    </el-button>
  </div>
</el-dialog>
```

Then I change the **name: "Checklist TEST"** and also label of first item **label: "Filter ok? TEST"**

Then I just click on cancel btn and open the dialog for the same row again.

And here is the thing..
And I'm trying to figure out why is just field "name" reset after I close the popup without save. Changes what I type into detail array are kept.

Illustration:
Init object fields:

```
"name": "Checklist",
    "detail": [
        {
            "label": "Filter OK?",
            "type": "text"
        },
```

Open first time and do the changes:

```
"name": "Checklist TEST",
    "detail": [
        {
            "label": "Filter OK? TEST",
            "type": "text"
        },
```

Close without save and open once again:

```
"name": "Checklist",
    "detail": [
        {
            "label": "Filter OK? TEST",
            "type": "text"
        },
```

**Screenshots:**
[image]
[image]

Name was reset but label not... I'm rly confused. What did I miss?

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-sanne-bm3w1?file=/src/main.js)

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you share some app screenshots of the process? Hard to visualize.

Comment: Sure, screenshots added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `Object.assign()` only makes a shallow copy of the Object and you are modifying a nested property `detail.name`. You need to make a deeper copy like

```js
this.temp = Object.assign({}, row, {
  detail: row.detail.map((item) => Object.assign({}, item)),
});
```

or using the spread operator

```js
this.temp = {
  ...row,
  detail: [...row.detail.map(item => ({...item}))]
};
```

see this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-fire-zz4wq?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:3354-3458)

You can also use a helper like [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#cloneDeep) in lodash

Comment: Perfect !  aha, now it finally makes sense to me ... thank you very much! I'm going to check it.